# Uploading a file using Windows.Web.Http from UWP app to a WebAPI web service

Tags: c#, rest, xaml, asp.net-web-api, uwp

My Windows 10 UWP app is calling a WebAPI web service that I have created. I need to send a JPG file from the UWP app to the server so that the server can store it into another application.

I am using `using Windows.Web.Http;` as recommended for UWP and using Windows Authentication to connect to the server.

When I perform a POST using the following code, I get the **IRandomAccessStream does not support the GetInputStreamAt method because it requires cloning** error shown below.

I am able to POST `HttpStringContent` to the same web service and receive the responses without any issue.

**The issue is when trying to send a file to the web service using `HttpStreamContent`.**

```
public async void Upload_FileAsync(string WebServiceURL, string FilePathToUpload)
{

    //prepare HttpStreamContent
    IStorageFile storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(FilePathToUpload);
    IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(storageFile);
    byte[] bytes = System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(buffer);
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    Windows.Web.Http.HttpStreamContent streamContent = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpStreamContent(stream.AsInputStream());


    //send request
    var myFilter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
    myFilter.AllowUI = false;
    var client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(myFilter);
    Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(WebServiceURL), streamContent);
    string stringReadResult = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

}
```

Full Error:

> {System.NotSupportedException: This IRandomAccessStream does not support the GetInputStreamAt method because it requires cloning and this stream does not support cloning.
>      at System.IO.NetFxToWinRtStreamAdapter.ThrowCloningNotSuported(String methodName)
>      at System.IO.NetFxToWinRtStreamAdapter.GetInputStreamAt(UInt64 position)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at }

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

After you get the file and begin to create a `HttpStreamContent` instance, you can try to use the [StorageFile.OpenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.openasync#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_OpenAsync_Windows_Storage_FileAccessMode_) method to get an `IRandomAccessStream` object, then put it as the `HttpStreamContent` object constructor parameter.

The code will be like this, you can have a try.

```
public async void Upload_FileAsync(string WebServiceURL, string FilePathToUpload)
{

    //prepare HttpStreamContent
    IStorageFile storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(FilePathToUpload);

    //Here is the code we changed
    IRandomAccessStream stream=await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    Windows.Web.Http.HttpStreamContent streamContent = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpStreamContent(stream);

    //send request
    var myFilter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
    myFilter.AllowUI = false;
    var client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(myFilter);
    Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(WebServiceURL), streamContent);
    string stringReadResult = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! this code gets rid of the error. however, what does the function on the WebAPI web service end look like to catch this call? I tried `public async Task<bool> UploadDocumentsAsync(byte[] fileUploadRequest)`  and `public async Task<bool> UploadDocumentsAsync([FromBody]byte[] fileUploadRequest)` and also tried the same with `IFormFile` but it doesn't catch the request sent with this call. pls help!

Comment: Pls see other question for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577563/cannot-get-file-sent-from-uwp-app-using-windows-web-http-to-webapi-web-service-c Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

In Web API Controller

```
public IHostingEnvironment _environment;
public UploadFilesController(IHostingEnvironment environment) // Create Constructor 
{
    _environment = environment;
}

[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public Task<ActionResult<string>> UploadFiles([FromForm]List<IFormFile> allfiles)
{
    string filepath = "";
    foreach (var file in allfiles)
    {
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        var upload = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "FileFolderName");
        if (!Directory.Exists(upload))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(upload);
        }
        string FileName = Guid.NewGuid() + extension;
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(upload, FileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
        filepath = Path.Combine("FileFolderName", FileName);
    }
    return Task.FromResult<ActionResult<string>>(filepath);
}
```

In yourpage.xaml.cs

```
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
.....
StorageFile file;
......

private async void btnFileUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Like Browse button 
{
    try
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".pdf");
        file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            //fetch file details
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

//When upload file
var http = new HttpClient();
var formContent = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();
var fileContent = new HttpStreamContent(await file.OpenReadAsync());
formContent.Add(fileContent, "allfiles", file.Name);
var response = await http.PostAsync(new Uri("Give API Path" + "UploadFiles", formContent);
string filepath = Convert.ToString(response.Content); //Give path in which file is uploaded
```

Hope this code helps you...

But remember `formContent.Add(fileContent, "allfiles", file.Name);` line is important and  `allfiles` is that name of parameter to fetch files in web api method `"public Task<ActionResult<string>> UploadFiles([FromForm]List<IFormFile> **allfiles**)"`

Thanks!!!