# How to download a file on the client device using Windows.Web.Http

Tags: c#, rest, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am working on a Windows to UWP app. A web service exists that when called (GET), returns a file. When the web service is triggered using a browser, it successfully downloads a file on the browser.

On the UWP app, I am using `Windows.Web.Http` to call the web service. I need to save get the file sent by the web service and save it on the device.

I currently have the following code. Not sure how to get the result from the web service and save to the file.

```
public async Task DownloadFile(string WebServiceURL, string PathToSave)
{

    var myFilter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
    myFilter.AllowUI = false;
    Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(myFilter);
    Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(WebServiceURL));


    using (IInputStream inputStream = await result.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync())
    {
        //not sure if this is correct and if it is, how to save this to a file
    }

}
```

Using `System.Web.Http`, I am able to easily do this using the following:

```
Stream stream = result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
var fileStream = File.Create(PathToSave);
await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
fileStream.Dispose();
stream.Dispose();
```

However, using `Windows.Web.Http`, I am not sure how I can do this. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this what you looking for?
like  this?

```
var myFilter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
            myFilter.AllowUI = false;
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(myFilter);
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(WebServiceURL));

            //not sure if this is correct and if it is, how to save this to a file
            var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("filename.tmp", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            using (var filestream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                await result.Content.WriteToStreamAsync(filestream);
                await filestream.FlushAsync();

            }
```

Comment: Ah yes! thanks a lot! could you also check if you can figure out my other question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577563 ? thanks!

Comment: You should avoid `FlushAsync` - the `using` block is going to close the resource anyway.